# Can I create integer array that dosen't have size beofre the algorithm?

Tags: arrays

Can I create a array that doesn't have size but after the algorithm has ran it would take a size?

**Example: Sieve of Eratosthenes**

I create a `int[]` prime.

I create counter that counts the number of primes in list of 100 and in the loop every time the algorithm fiends a prime number size of the prime is counter and `prime[counter] = p`.

Or we can have to use the same algorithm once to decides the size of the array and once to declare the variables in the array.

What I'm working is I have class called **sort** and I have class called **even**.

The job of my program is to store all even integers in order from small to large given the input to user to enter 5 numbers, the class even would take those even numbers and store them from small to large. So as long as user don't enter any thing the size of the array even is unknown.

Comment: depends on which programming language you are using.

Comment: Java or Python.

Comment: python:
`array = []`

java:
`ArrayList<Object> array = new ArrayList<>();`